# Can Not Call Datasource from Repository

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I want to retrieve data from Datasource. But turns out it didnt get executed at all. How can i solve it? here is my code

**Repository.kt**

```
    // all logcat in repository is executed
    override fun getDetailGame(id: Int): Flow<Resource<Game>> {
        Log.d("Repo", "getDetailGame: called")
        return flow {
            Log.d("Repo", "getDetailGame: before flow")
            remoteDataSource.getDetailGame(id)
            Log.d("Repo", "getDetailGame: after flow")
        }
    }
```

**Datasource.kt**

```
suspend fun getDetailGame(id: Int): Flow<ApiResponse<GameResponse>> =
    flow {
        try {
            // didnt get executed all
            Log.d(TAG, "getDetailGame: called")
            val response = apiService.getDetailGame(id)
            if (response != null) {
                emit(ApiResponse.Success(response))
            } else {
                emit(ApiResponse.Empty)
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            emit(ApiResponse.Error(ex.message.toString()))
            Log.e(TAG, "getDetailGame: ${ex.message} ")
        }
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

Edit: add additional code for other file

**ApiResponse.kt** (response state management for the datasource)

```
sealed class ApiResponse<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : ApiResponse<T>()
    data class Error(val errorMessage: String) : ApiResponse<Nothing>()
    object Empty : ApiResponse<Nothing>()
}
```

**Resource.kt** (state management for UI like loading state etc)

```
sealed class Resource<T>(val data: T? = null, val message: String? = null) {
    class Success<T>(data: T) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Loading<T>(data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String, data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data, message)
}
```

**GameResponse.kt** (same like Game but with serializedname for json)

```
data class GameResponse(
    @field:SerializedName("id")
    var id: Int,

    @field:SerializedName("name")
    var title: String,

    @field:SerializedName("released")
    var released: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("metacritic")
    var metacritic: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("metacritic_url")
    var metacriticUrl: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("background_image")
    var bgImage: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("description")
    var description: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("game_series_count")
    var gameSeriesCount: Int? = 0
)
```

**Game.kt** (same like GameResponse but the clean version of it)

```
data class Game(
    var id: Int,
    var title: String,
    var released: String? = null,
    var metacritic: Int? = null,
    var metacriticUrl: Int? = null,
    var bgImage: String? = null,
    var description: String? = null,
    var gameSeriesCount: Int? = 0
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flows are cold streams, this means they wont be executed until you collect them.
If you are trying to convert `Flow<ApiResponse>` to `Flow<Resource>`, you should use the `map` function. If you need a more complex transformation, use `transform` instead.

```
override fun getDetailGame(id: Int): Flow<Resource<GameResponse>> {
    return remoteDataSource.getDetailGame(id).map { response ->
        when (response) {
            ApiResponse.Empty -> Resource.Loading()
            is ApiResponse.Success -> Resource.Success(response.data)
            is ApiResponse.Error -> Resource.Error(response.errorMessage)
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you need to emit a value before perform the transformation:

```
override fun getDetailGame(id: Int): Flow<Resource<GameResponse>> = flow {
    emit(Resource.Loading())
    emitAll(
        remoteDataSource.getDetailGame(id).map { response ->
            when (response) {
                is ApiResponse.Success -> Resource.Success(response.data)
                is ApiResponse.Error -> Resource.Error(response.errorMessage)
                ApiResponse.Empty -> Resource.Error("")
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Any reference on how to do the conversion?

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to do and in order to help you i need to see these classes: ApiResponse, GameResponse, Resource, Game

Comment: ApiResponse and Resource is sealed class for state management. Game and GameResponse is the same data class, GameResponse has serializedname for retrieveng key from JSON and will map it into the Game data class. The whole properties of both class is the same.

Comment: can you add them in your question?

Comment: added to the post sir

Comment: I edited my answer but you should delete your Game class. Having a duplicate class makes no sense